# jQuery - Register an element in the DOM after setting html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, where I set the innerHTML after a button has been clicked:

```
$('#headerDiv').html('Welcome [<a href=\'javascript:void(0);\' id=\'logout_button\'>Logout</a>]');
```

However, the new element `logout_button` isn't registered in the `DOM`, so I can't capture click events using the traditional `$('#logout_button').click()`.

Is it possible to register `logout_button` in the `DOM` just after it's been set with the `html()` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Delegate the event**

```
$('#headerDiv').on('click', '#logout_button', function() {
     // Your code
});
```

This will make sure the event is attached to the `dynamically added` element by the concept of event bubbling.

Comment: Wow. That was much simpler than I'd thought. Thanks! I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to :-)

Comment: @Sus O.T, should we start to link to an already existent answer? `;)`

Comment: There's only a thousand to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

If delegation isn't your cup of tea, you can bind your click handler to the button before attaching the button. Do that by creating DOM elements and appending them:

```
var btn = $('<a />').text('Logout').attr({
        "href": "javascript:void(0);",
        "id": "logout_button"
    }).click(function (e) {
        // do logout stuff
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
$('#headerDiv').append(btn);
```

This has the added bonus of ensuring you are adding valid elements to the DOM.